# How second-order differential equations do not violate causality?

Tags: classical-mechanics, causality, arrow-of-time

The second order differential equations are time reversible. That means: they don't distinguish the time arrow direction. There is no reason for the time to flow forward.

My professor told me that there are two solutions to such equations, one of which describes processes going forward and one backward in time. The "backward" solution violates causality, so we say that only the "forward" solution is physical and the other simply don't exist.

Is this explanation correct?

And a second question: How is causality not violated?

Comment: A damped oscillator doesn't really make sense in reverse.  I'm really not sure what they were even trying to imply with any of that though.

Comment: @JMac If you're familiar with a Lagrangian that obtains damped motion, it's easy to see why it's not time symmetric.

Comment: @J.G. Even from just basic DE's it's fairly intuitive why that isn't the case, especially when you consider the associated physical system it represents.  Most objects that act (approximately) like an ideal damper utilize dissapative effects, not much ability to make that happen in reverse.

Comment: I believe that the problem is How current physics model phenomena, in sake of simplicity, only through Lipschitz diff. eqns. so they can hold uniqueness of solutions, but as example, no scalar Lipschitz diff. eq. can hold solutions of finite duration (see papers "Finite Time Controllers" and "Finite Time Differential Equations" by V.T. Haimo -1985)... since is no wideknown issue, is not take into account when modeling reality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Causality is not a hard-science topic as much as it is a philosophy of science topic.  Causality is actually a *huge* issue in philosophy because, while typically want to say causality exists, it's actually *markedly* difficult to pen a description of it in a language which can stand up to the rigors of philosophy.

So your professor, in describing these equations, is showing an assumption he has made which is that the universe is causal.  He's got a lifetime of empirical evidence to defend that assumption, but philosophy would say it isn't quite enough to be a "proof."

So when facing a reversible 2nd order equation, your professor is simply saying "ignore the 'other' solution as an artifact of the mathematics."

In "reality," it is not possible to set up a *perfect* second order system.  In the real world, there's all sorts of other real life effects like thermal effects and gravitational effects that lead your real-life experimental apparatus to demonstrate a preference to *approximate* the "forward" solution from your differential equation.  A great example of this is mentioned by JMac in the comments.  A damped oscillator has some entropic force such as friction taking energy out of the system, and that almost compels the system to progress in the "forward" direction.

Similar issues show up in quantum mechanics.  Some of the interpretations of QM involve a backwards propagating waveform to make all of the equations line up.  Such interpretations open themselves to the philosophical question of what does a backwards propagating waveform *mean* in the real world, a world which appears to be subject to the laws of causality.

Answer (score 1):

It is not just second order differential equations, but all our local interaction equations that are the problem.  They are all time reversible, but the universe as we observe it is not.  When was the last time you saw an egg unscramble?  We look to two things:  the increase of entropy and the collapse of the wave function.  This is a big subject, worthy of a book, and there are many.  Onr I have read is The Physics of Time Asymmetry: P. C. W. Davies which talks about entropy and shows it isn't as simple as you think because of [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) which says the volume in phase space is constant.  The second, which I can't find the reference for, shows that as the universe is clearly not in thermal equilibrium you should expect entropy to increase in both directions from now.  The only reason not to is our memory that the universe was in an even lower entropy state in the past.  In that case you have to appeal to the big bang as an extremely low entropy state which we are living off of.